# How can I run a Systemd service under an Active Directory account?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, domain, samba4

I'm running a NAS under Ubuntu 17.10 and I have changed the Samba configuration so that it now runs as a domain controller.

The next step I'm trying to do is to modify some Systemd services on the NAS so that they run with a domain account and no longer with a local account.

For example: `/lib/systemd/system/syncthing@.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization for %I
Documentation=man:syncthing(1)
After=network.target
Wants=syncthing-inotify@.service

[Service]
User=%i
ExecStart=/usr/bin/syncthing -no-browser -no-restart -logflags=0
Restart=on-failure
SuccessExitStatus=3 4
RestartForceExitStatus=3 4

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Can this be done and if yes, how? I have tried to change the line `User=%i` into `User=SAMDOM\syncthing` but after a restart of the service Systemd throws the error:

```
Invalid user/group name or numeric ID: SAMDOM\syncthing
```

I can find the user via `wbinfo -u` and also `id "SAMDOM\syncthing"` shows me the correct UIDs and GIDs. My search on the Internet to find more information about using domain accounts with Systemd was not successful, so I hope that somebody here knows how to do it.

P.s.: If additional information (e.g. logs, Samba configuration) is needed I will provide it ASAP.

Comment: Try just using the username with out specifying the domain and so just "syncthing"

Answer (score 2):

I have tried it and it works. My problem was that the old local account named "syncthing" was still there and caused a naming conflict. After removing the local account Systemd uses the domain account and everything works like a charm.

From my understanding I also could just keep the `User=%i` in the unit file because it then uses the name "syncthing" automatically.

That was easier than I thought!